# How to build an Appcelerator Titanium iOS Module that requires a CocoaPods pod

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to build a native iOS module that requires a CocoaPods pod (https://cocoapods.org/pods/NearbyMessages).

I created a new module using the Titanium Command Line Interface:

```
ti create --type=module --platforms=ios ...
```

I followed the instructions from CocoaPods (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) to create a Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyModule' do
  pod 'NearbyMessages'
end
```

I placed the Podfile into the "iphone" directory of my iOS module directory:

```
MyModule
 - LICENCE
 - README
 - assets
 - documentation
 - example
 - iphone
   - Podfile
   - ...
   - timodule.xml
   - titanium.xcconfig
```

I installed the pod using the following command:

```
pod install
```

I opened XCode with the newly created *.xcworkspace file and added the following line to the end of the titanium.xcconfig file:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyModule/Pods-MyModule.debug.xcconfig"
```

But unfortunately this leads to several errors, like:

- "'Ti.Module.h' file not found" in the header file of my module
- several "cannot use 'super' because it is a root class" in the implementation file of my module

I tried different variations of including the Pods config file but none of them were successful.

Can anybody please tell me how a correct XCode setup should look like to use the NearbyMessages pod in a native iOS module?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: @Preetha I added my pod file to my question. I guess I already have the relevant headers added to it, right?

Comment: Sorry @Preetha, but I'm not sure what you mean. I followed the instructions from developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started, but this is not specific for creating a native Appcelerator Titanium iOS Module.

Answer (score 2):

The build.py file needs to be updated to use the workspace file instead.  Inside the build_module method, add the -workspace and -scheme parameters to xcodebuild.  The lines should look like this:

`rc = os.system("xcodebuild -workspace %s.xcworkspace -scheme %s -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release" %(manifest['name'],manifest['name']))`

`rc = os.system("xcodebuild -workspace %s.xcworkspace -scheme %s -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release" %(manifest['name'],manifest['name']))`

After making this change, `python build.py` should work successfully.

I'm just at the point of figuring this out for myself, so there may need to be more steps, but that got me past the point you are at.

Comment: Thanks Ron! I merged HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS from my Pods xcconfig file with HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in titanium.xcconfig file. When I apply your suggested changes in my local build.py file it seems the script is able to successfully build the module but it ends with an error message: 
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: no input files specified 
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: build/libcom.company.module.my.a (No such file or directory)

Comment: how did you end up fixing this? I'm stuck at the same point you were

Comment: The build.py file is now deprecated. Anyway of doing this now.